# Can I simplify logarithm of logarithm.

Tags: calculus

It it possible to simplify Logarithm of logarithm:

log log x

(for example, make it log (base 4) x.

Comment: In short: No, not usually.

Comment: I just need to show whether log log x is bigger or square root x is bigger? how to do that?

Comment: Sqrt(x) = Exp(Log(x)/2)

Comment: @MatsGranvik That is incorrect.  You are using the “exp” function (which has base e) but you are also using the common logarithm (which has base 10).  You can either write $\sqrt{x}= e^{\frac{\ln x}{2}}$ or $\sqrt{x}=10^{\frac{\log x}{2}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to simplify (although it might be possible to make it very, very complicated).

As a side note, we have
$$
\log_{4} x = \frac{\log x}{\log 4}
$$
so there's that.

Comment: Thanks .. I just need to show whether log log x is bigger or square  root x is bigger? how to do that?

Comment: for $x > e$, where the function is defined, compare the intial values and the derivatives.

Comment: @user836026 i think we can't answer two questions here .

Comment: @user836026 you write down the inequality you want to show, and raise $e$ to the power of both sides. What you have now should be easier to compare.

Comment: @Arthur please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530871/which-is-bigger-log-logx-square-root-x-log-x-to-power-2